# can dispose method clear manage code object?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

As garbage collection can't clear unmanaged code.To clear unmanaged code we use dispose method,but can vice versa possible?can we clear manage code object using dispose method?

Answer (score 4):

A `Dispose` method implementation *might* set some fields to `null`, potentially making "child" objects eligible for garbage collection even if the containing object itself isn't eligible for garbage collection.

It can't forcibly delete objects though - the closest it could come would be to call [`GC.Collect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect.aspx).

`Dispose` certainly doesn't *have* to clear fields at all though - for example, with [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), you can access the data within the stream (via [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) or [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx)) even after disposing of it.

Usually it's better (IMO) to just let the garbage collector get on with what it's good at.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to force this - you could implement IDisposable on your class and then use it within a `using(){}` block once it falls out of scope it will be cleaned up on the next `GC.Collect` cycle, which can be forced by calling the method.